# Unable to display string from backend to Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I am unable to display some string from my custom view backend to django template. The string from backend is able to send over to the client side browser but still unable to display. The error message that I am trying to display is a lockout message from django-axes. it is a custom view function that returns a HttpResponse(JsonResponse(response_data)) where the `response_data` is as shown in the image inserted.

Below is what I have tried.

**HTML**

```
<div class="login-form clrbg-before">
  <p class="text-success" id="login-success" style="display: none;"></p>
  <form role="agent-login" class="login" id="" action="{% url 'agent-login' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group togglepassword-right">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback" id="togglePassword"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="text-danger text-center" id="password-error" style="display:none;"> {{ errors }}</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button data-request="ajax-submit" data-target="[role='agent-login']" class="btn-1 " type="button"> Login now </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="gray-clr" id="agent-forgot"> Forgot Password? </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def agent_login(request):
    start = time.time()
    sop(start)
    response_data = {'login': "Failed"}
    redirect_url = ''
    data = []
    error = False
    errors = {}
    result = 'FAIL'
    message = ''
    response_status = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

    if request.POST:
        redirect_url = ''
        data = []
        error = False
        errors = {}
        result = 'FAIL'
        message = ''
        response_status = HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        if not email:
            message = 'Please enter email.'
            errors.update({'email': message})
            error = True
        elif not validateEmail(email):
            message = 'Please enter valid email.'
            errors.update({'email': message})
            error = True

        if not password:
            message = 'Please enter password.'
            errors.update({'password': message})
            error = True

        if not error:
            try:
                Uparceluser.objects.exclude(
                    status_id__in=[settings.DELETE, 21]
                    ).get(email__iexact=email,usertype_id=settings.USERTYPE_AGENT)

                try:
                    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password, usertype=settings.USERTYPE_AGENT)
                    print("user: %s" % user.name)
                    if user.is_authenticated and user.is_active:
                        if user.status_id == 2:
                            message = 'Your account is inactive. Please verify your email address.'
                            errors.update({'password': message})
                        elif user.status_id == 21:
                            message = 'Your account does not exist. Please contact administrator.'
                            errors.update({'password': message})
                        elif user.status_id == 3 and user.usertype_id == 1:
                            message = 'Your account is blocked. Please contact administrator.'
                            errors.update({'password': message})
                        else:
                            login(request, user)
                            data = {
                                "message_code": "agent_login_success"
                            }

                            response_status = HTTP_200_OK
                            result = 'SUCCESS'
                            message = 'redirect'
                            redirect_url = reverse('agent:profile')
                except AttributeError:
                    message = 'The email or password does not match'
                    errors.update({'password': message})
            except Uparceluser.DoesNotExist:
                message = 'The email or password does not match'
                errors.update({'password': message})

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            'data': data,
            'status': result,
            'error': error,
            'errors': errors,
            'redirect': redirect_url,
            'message': message
        }),
        status = response_status
    )
```

**from browser**
[image]

**EDITED**

The following code is what is displaying as depicted in the inserted image.

```
def user_lockout(request, credentials):
    """
    Custom accout lockout message for django-axes.
    change custom_account_lockout_message accordingly to what you need.
    """
    response_data = {
        "login": "Failed",
        "error": settings.CUSTOM_AXES_SOFT_LOCKOUT_MESSAGE
    }
    return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(response_data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the browser screenshot isn't included in `views.py`.

Are you sure that's the correct file?

Also, I'm not sure if `{{ errors }}` can display a list, but it should be a string defined as `errors = 'list of error messages'` instead of a list defined as `errors = {}`.

Comment: hi! Ive included the snippet of the code. thanks for responding

Comment: If `HttpResponse(JsonResponse(response_data))` is a string, it can be displayed with `{{ classname.user_lockout }}` instead of `{{ errors }}`. Editing the comment with a link to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/#id6

Comment: Youre a genius! I have managed to resolve my issue by using custom register filter! Didn't know it existed as I am new to Django. Thank you so much for pointing me towards the correct direction!